# Is there a way to configure VSCODE to work with CVS?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

At my company we have our code in a CVS repository. I really like using vscode and use it as my primary editor but right now the only way to work with our CVS repository is to use an external tool to do the pulls and commits. Right now I am using eclipse as my cvs client. Is there a extension that provides CVS integration, is there a way to configure a non-cvs SCM or is there a way to build an extension to provide CVS integration?

Any Help woudl be great.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I switched to phpstorm which worked well enough. Fortunately a few weeks from now we are finally moving to Git, at which point pretty much any IDE is an option as it is so widely supported as a integrated source control. This basically means that as our company grows staff can use the IDE they are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that without writing some Javascript your only solution is to use the regular external tools.

You could write a visual studio code extension in Javascript to support the CVS version control system - support for all the others like Git, mercurial etc are written the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem at the moment.
Even though this discussion is quite old, I thought to add my 1 cent here as search engine found this as top result.
Most promising way to add cvs support to vscode seems to be https://github.com/jackie-h/vscode-scm-cvs,
but i'm still trying to figure out is it any good and how to use it

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!